# Subtracting the background from the Lorentzian

Tags: plotting, fitting

I am plotting a dataset which is a Lorentzian, for the fitting, I need to subtract the background. I want to subtract a line from the dataset which connects the first and last points of my dataset.
Here is the dataset [Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mlkiQny59utR-JMV4NfDMzog8Re1oy4f/view?usp=sharing). I do not know how to proceed with it.

```
Data = Import["Documents\\24.asc"];
Ampvsf1 = Data[[All, {1, 4}]];
graph = ListPlot[Ampvsf1, PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

I am attaching an image to make myself more clear

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
iF = Interpolation[Ampvsf1[[{1, -1}]], InterpolationOrder -> 1];

dif = Ampvsf1 - Thread[{0, iF /@ Ampvsf1[[All, 1]]}];

ListPlot[{Ampvsf1, dif, Style[Ampvsf1[[{1, -1}]], Red]}, Joined -> {False, False, True}]
```

[image]

Comment: This works for me, Can we do the take the average of the first 10 points and the last 10 points to increase the accuracy.

Comment: @Shelender, maybe you can try `fit[x_] = Fit[Join[Ampvsf1[[;; 10]], Ampvsf1[[-10 ;;]]], {1, x}, x];
dif = Ampvsf1 - Thread[{0, fit /@ Ampvsf1[[All, 1]]}];
ListPlot[{Ampvsf1, dif, 
  Style[Thread[{#, fit /@ #}] &@Ampvsf1[[All, 1]], Red]}, 
 Joined -> {False, False, True}]`?